# String literals to PTCHAR is deprecated

Tags: c++, unicode, lpcstr

I am working on Legacy code where a string literal is assigned to a variable of type `PTCHAR` (pointer to char) which is defined in the header: `typedef WCHAR TCHAR, *PTCHAR;`

```cpp
PTCHAR str;
str = _tcsrchr(dir, '\\');
*(str++)=0;

str = TEXT("This is stackoverflow");
```

I am getting a warning 'conversion from a string literal to pointer-to-character (non-const) is deprecated',
I understand warning is coming because a const is assigned to a non-const pointer variable, but I can't make str CONST(LPCSTR) because it is being modified in code as `*(str++)=0;`

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: There is a difference between a non-const pointer to const and a const pointer to non-const. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Use `LPCTSTR` in-place of `PTCHAR`  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Comment: I did the same thing, but then *(str++)=0 will throw an error.

Comment: The string `"This is stackoverflow"` is const (probably in read-only memory).  Any attempt to modify it is Undefined Behaviour.  Using `LPCTSTR` will give you compilation errors instead of UB.

Comment: Please make a [mcve], especially of the part with the `*(str++)=0;`. The problem might be there. Maybe in the shape of a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: updated the required code

Comment: @RichardCritten a string literal is unlikely to be in read-only memory in a modern system. That doesn't make it any less UB, but does lessen the chances that you'll notice.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't know that; I though the loader could mark pages as read only and that's where string literals (and other constant data) would be loaded.

Comment: any suggestions on this?? :|  how to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the string later, you will need to make a copy of it, for example using `_wcsdup()`. Don't forget to `free()` it when done.

Comment: @Yunnosch Why do you think string is not modified? `*(str++)=0;` is string a modification.

Comment: @Codo You are right. I was over-focussing on the `str++` NOT changing it. Sorry. (By the way; good style asking "why" instead of saying "wrong", though I was.)